# How to have a Scala standalone application that uses the playframework libraries

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have this simple test Scala application, which a blocking http request:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.0-M1"
```

**Test.scala**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.ws._
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val wsClient = WS.client
    val body = getBody(wsClient.url("http://example.com/").get())
    println(s"body: $body")
  }

  def getBody(future: Future[WSResponse]) = {
    val response = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf);
    if (response.status != 200)
      throw new Exception(response.statusText);
    response.body
  }
}
```

This application fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT for Play 2.5:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient

import scala.concurrent.Future

object Main {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val wsClient = AhcWSClient()

    call(wsClient)
      .andThen { case _ => wsClient.close() }
      .andThen { case _ => system.terminate() }
  }

  def call(wsClient: WSClient): Future[Unit] = {
    wsClient.url("http://www.google.com").get().map { response =>
      val statusText: String = response.statusText
      println(s"Got a response $statusText")
    }
  }
}
```

Please see:

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#using-wsclient
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients

for more detailed examples of standalone WSClient usage.  If you are migrating from earlier versions, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Play-WS-upgrades-to-AsyncHttpClient-2

For Play 2.4:

Do not use raw AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder for HTTPS -- it does not configure a secure SSLContext with hostname validation.

You can create a new WSClient instance using the following code:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ning._
import play.api.libs.ws._

val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(DefaultWSClientConfig()).build()
val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
val wsClient:WSClient = new NingWSClient(builder.build())
```

Please note that this will start up threads which will not be closed until you close the client:

```
wsClient.underlying[NingWSClient].close()
```

and you may run into memory leaks if you don't close it.

Comment: The clearest example of how to do this that I've seen, thanks Will.

Comment: all is deprecated now in 2.5.x.

Comment: Hi @ses -- please see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#using-wsclient and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients

Comment: When I run this with play 2.4.8, the app doesn't exit. Some other thread is still alive. Is there another cleanup step?

Comment: You need to call `wsClient.close()` after you're done.

Comment: Here is a version for Play 2.3: https://gist.github.com/ScalaWilliam/39d9fc69204a9428b95c

Comment: I had threads sticking around even after `wsClient.close()`, but that turned out to be because I used the implicit Play execution context (for processing the futures returned from WS). Changing that to the Scala global one fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Play 2.4 makes it very easy to utilize WS in a standalone app.

The following [gist](https://gist.github.com/cdimascio/46b2b7d2986636c1189c) provides a nice working example and the following [blog post](http://carminedimascio.com/2015/02/how-to-use-the-play-ws-library-in-a-standalone-scala-app/) provides a nice explanation.

Here are the highlights.

Configure build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.0-M2"
)
```

Initialize the WS client

```
val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(DefaultWSClientConfig()).build
val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build)
```

Use WS

```
client.url("http://www.example.com").get
```

Release WS resources

```
client.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

A started PlayApplication contains a client instance, [which WS.client simply points to it](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L114). Since you won't start a Play application, You have to create your own client, like this:

```
val client = {
  val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
  new play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build())
}
client.url("http://example.com/").get()
```

Have a look on [my project](https://github.com/tabdulradi/akka-auth/blob/e74187f4a99c88df7a94db3db0650663cd5ebfbc/src/main/scala/com/abdulradi/akka/auth/ServiceFetcher.scala) for a similar usecase, I am using play-ws and play-json, without Play itself.